# recount to the other vs recount to each other

Tags: word-usage

1. They recounted to the other what  had happened to them.
2. They  recounted to each other what had happened to them.
3. They recounted  each other what had happened to them.

Which sentence is more correct?

Answer (score 2):

It depends in part on how many people are involved. If there are only two, you may use any of these:

> a) They recounted to each other what had happened to them.
>   b) Each recounted to the other what had happened to him<sup>†</sup>
>   c) They recounted, each to the other, what had happened to them.

If there are three or more people involved, *other* becomes *others* in b) and c), but not in a).

Note that *recount* does not take an indirect object in Modern and Post-Modern Englishes: you must include a *to* to designate the hearer.

<sup>† If *each* is your subject, formal correctness calls for a singular pronoun, *him*, in subsequent references. However, contemporary usage prefers *them* unless it is established that all the people involved are male.</sup>

Comment: Although [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=recount+to+one+another%2Crecount+to+each+other&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crecount%20to%20one%20another%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecount%20to%20each%20other%3B%2Cc0) suggests *recount to each other* is still the dominant form, I think I'd be more likely to use *recount to **one another*** (which according to that chart is still gaining traction, even though it's not *yet* as common as the ***each other*** form).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, if it comes to that, I wouldn't use *recounted* at all, but *told*--and I'd be 50/50 on *each other/one another*.

Comment: When posting that first comment I was going to also make the point that ***recount*** sounds a bit formal/dated to me in such contexts. (But there wasn't enough room in the comment to include [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=recount+to+one+another%2Crecount+to+each+other%2Ctold+one+another%2Ctold+each+other&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crecount%20to%20one%20another%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecount%20to%20each%20other%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctold%20one%20another%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctold%20each%20other%3B%2Cc0) to support me there! :)